# changing title of a plot inside a do.call

Tags: r, graphics, cross-correlation, do.call

The function my.ccf generates a plot among other things.

```
my.ccf <- function(dat)
{
require(forecast)
modx <- auto.arima(dat[,1])
modx$series <- colnames(dat)[1]
mody <- Arima(dat[,2], model=modx)
mody$series <- colnames(dat)[2]
ccf1 <- ccf(residuals(modx), residuals(mody), type="correlation", ylab="CCF", 
            main=paste(colnames(dat)[1], "&", colnames(dat)[2], sep=" "))
return(list(modx=modx, mody=mody, ccf=ccf1))    
}
dat1 <- data.frame(p=rnorm(50), q=rnorm(50)); my.ccf(dat1)
```

The figure produced has 'p & x' etc as title

I’m applying this function on another data.frame (dat2) using do.call inside the function year.ccf. First it'll subset the passed data.frame by year (I have separate function to do that. For illustrative purpose I use for loop here) and then apply  my.ccf on the paired combination of column named 'x' with the columns given in var.do. Length of var.do varies form 3 to 9. I have to do it repeatedly many times (more than 500 times) on different data frame and trying to do as automatic as possible.

```
year.ccf1 <- function(dat, var.do=c('a','b'))
{
year.form <- format(dat2$date, '%Y')
dat$year <- factor(year.form, levels=unique(year.form), ordered=TRUE)
yl <- levels(dat$year)
ydat <- list()
for(i in 1:length(yl))
ydat[[i]] <- subset(dat,year==yl[i])
wdat <- list()
for(i in 1:length(yl)){  
a <- list()
for(j in 1:length(var.do)){
#par(mfrow=c(2,2))
a[[j]] <- do.call(my.ccf, list(ydat[[i]][,eval(c(var.do[j],'x'))]))
}
names(a) <- var.do
wdat[[i]] <- a         
}
names(wdat) <- yl
return(wdat)
}
date <- seq(as.Date("2011/1/1"), as.Date("2013/8/1"),  by = "months")
dat2 <- data.frame(date=date,x =rnorm(length(date)), y=rnorm(length(date)),        
a=rnorm(length(date)),b=rnorm(length(date)))
pdf("./temp/dat2.pdf")
A <- year.ccf1(dat2, var.do=c('a', 'b'))
dev.off()
```

I'm trying to change the title of each plot in dat2.pdf to have Year stamp with the column name, such as "Year 2011: CCF of a & x'. Not sure whether I'm missing something obvious or don't understand how to put to argument in one do.call like below.

```
do.call(my.ccf, main=paste("Year ", yl[i], var.do[j], " & x", sep=" "), list(ydat[[i]
[,eval(c(var.do[j],'x'))]))
```

Also trying to put multiple plot in one page to make the pdf file smaller in size. I tried with par(mfrow) (uncommented) to handle second issue but failed.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should first give an extra argument to `my.ccf`. For example:

```
my.ccf <- function(dat,year=NA)
{
   ...
  title=paste(colnames(dat)[1], "&", colnames(dat)[2], sep=" ")
  if(!is.na(year))
    title <- paste('Year', year,': CCF',title)
  ccf1 <- ccf(residuals(modx), ..., main=title)
  .....
}
```

Then You change your `do.call` to something like this :

```
 do.call(my.ccf, list(dat=list(ydat[[i]][,eval(c(var.do[j],'x'))]),year=i))
```

That' said  think your `year.ccf1` function is over complicated and you extremely inefficient. Try to rewrite it using `outer` and `mapply` for example.

```
year.ccf1 <- function(dat, var.do=c('a','b'))
{
  dat$year <- factor(format(dat$date, '%Y'))
  ydat <- split(dat,dat$year)
  outer(names(ydat),var.do,function(x,y)
    Map(function(i,j)
        do.call(my.ccf, list(dat=ydat[[i]][,c(j,'x')],year=i))
           ,x,y)
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for both the code and making me efficient. The calculation are fine but gives an error massage ` 
  dims [product 6] do not match the length of object [18]'. This is due to using _outer()_ which expects the length should be 18 but it returns a list of 6. Any idea to fix this? I tried lapply() as both the input and output are lists but that generates other errors as well.

Comment: Got it! `outer(...mapply(.....)),x,y, **SIMPLIFY=FALSE**))` do the tricks. output from each combination now stored in a list.

Comment: @ykh good! I Will update my answer , another option is to replace `mapply` by `Map`.

Comment: I need to collect enough reputation before voting up your answer. I'll do that as soon as I got enough reputation. :-)

Comment: my version and your version? I was thinking about that right now. Will be able to do it as your version is working. In the meantime I got another version using two foreach loop. May be benchmark all three.

Comment: @ykh you can use `microbenchmark` package. Many examples here in SO.